# <jsp:getProperty> strange behaviour

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I have a bean class whit set/get methods and from a JSP page when I try
to get a property with:

1. `<jsp:getProperty name="p" property="firstName"></jsp:getProperty>`
   and the method in the bean is named as: `getFirstName` or `getfirstName` the property is returned;
2. `<jsp:getProperty name="p" property="FirstName"></jsp:getProperty>` and the method in the bean is named as: `getFirstName` or `getfirstName` the property is not returned and I have this exception: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6054: Cannot find any information on property 'FirstName' in a bean`

Why? I know that for bean rules when I write a property name the container try to find a getter or setter method that start with get or set and then continues with the property name indicated (no matter if it starts with the first letter capitalized???)

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use `getFirstName()` with `${p.firstName}`? The `<jsp:getProperty>` predates the EL era and is worthless since then (since a decade). See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: Yes I did it but my question stay opened also with EL.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's also why I posted it as a **comment**, not as an **answer** :) The answer is basically already given.

Answer (score 2):

Java beans rely on naming conventions for introspection, see the spec here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html

You'll be most interested in section 8.3 (page 55 in the PDF).

Comment: Thanks I read it and I understand that my code not work because I try to find a property named FirstName that does not exists because the property name inferred by the methods is always firstName also if the method is written as FirstName because the first letter is lower-cased...

Answer (score 1):

No you are worng,

when you create getter and setter methods method will be created as getXxxx() and setXxxx() if the attribute is private String xxxx;

So please follow the code convention while creating getter and setter methods.
this will resolve the issue.

So ur property will be lowercase letter as first_name in ur bean class